# Why does pytest.raises fail when iterating over a list?

Tags: pytest

I wrote a pytest test for setter method to check its ability to reject invalid input.

```
def test_set_x_invalid(out):
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        out.x = -1
    # No change to previously set value when input rejected
    assert(out.x == 30)
```

The method under test correctly raises a `ValueException`, which `pytest.raises` catches and interprets as a pass.

However, when I place a several bad inputs in a list and then use a for loop to access the list elements, `pytest.raises` complains that no exception is raised

```
    def test_set_x_invalid(out):
        shouldReject = [-1, 31, 87123761246, "foo", None, True, False, ";oaisdfhluhxcvlisd"]
        for badx in shouldReject:
            with pytest.raises(ValueError):
>               out.x = badx
E               Failed: DID NOT RAISE <class 'ValueError'>
```

Does this mean  `raises` can't be used in a loop body??

Comment: There should be no problem with using `pytest.raises` within a loop.  I can not offer further guidance without seeing the code for object `out`, the error is not reproducible..

Comment: @wim - I've posted repro-able code below.

Comment: Argh.  An off by one error in my test condition.  Disregard last post.